# multiple commands on button press

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

How would I change this code so that I can also have it start a function called `Drop_down_menu()`

```
done_btn = Button(root, text = "Done", command = lambda: root.destroy())       
done_btn.pack()
```

I have looked at previous articles which say use a function and have the operations there but then it says root is not defined.

Comment: About which "previous articles" do you say? This is code using module TK? Be more specific

Comment: Show your code, and the resulting error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function and pass `root` as a variable to it:

```
def myfunction(root):
    root.destroy()
    Drop_down_menu()

done_btn = Button(root, text = "Done", command = lambda: myfunction(root))       
done_btn.pack()
```

For more details on how to use `callbacks` in Tkinter [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm)'s a good tutorial. Here's an example from that tutorial on how to use a callback with a parameter:

```
def callback(number):
    print "button", number

Button(text="one",   command=lambda: callback(1)).pack()
Button(text="two",   command=lambda: callback(2)).pack()
Button(text="three", command=lambda: callback(3)).pack()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this error comes up: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

Comment: @user8469209 Try `Button(root, text = "Done", command = lambda: myfunction(root))` so the `command` is a function of no parameters.

Comment: @AMagoon that would call `myfunction(root)` immediately, not on Button press

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
done_btn = Button(root, text = "Done", command = lambda: [root.destroy(),
                                                          Drop_down_menu()])       
done_btn.pack()
```

hope this answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in an object orientated manner, which would clean up your code some by letting you dodge the use of `lambda`:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.btn = Button(self.root, text="Done", command=self.command)
        self.btn.pack()
    def command(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        print("Output")

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

for call multipe functions or commands you need to use lambda like this:

```
test_button = Button(text="your_text_button", command=lambda:[function1(),function2()])
text_button.pack()
```